# How to merge cURL responses into one array?

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I'm calling a function to get data from 3 different sources.
The `$returnedData` response is always an array. How to merge all 3 responses into one array?

```
function getData($xPostURL,$xToken,$xTokenSecret,$xAccount)
{ 
    $datatopost = array (
        "token" =>  $xToken,
        "tokenSecret" => $xTokenSecret,
        "account" => $xAccount,
    );

    $ch = curl_init ($xPostURL);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $returnedData = curl_exec ($ch);

    echo $returnedData;
}

getData("http://www.example.com/foo.php","","","");
getData("http://www.example.org/bar.php","","","");
getData("http://www.example.net/helloworld.php","","","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use: [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$a = getData("http://www.example.com/foo.php","","","");
$b = getData("http://www.example.org/bar.php","","","");
$c = getData("http://www.example.net/helloworld.php","","","");

$r = array_merge($a,$b,$c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge Arrays with this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php
If wel use this function your code will look something like this:

```
function getData($xPostURL,$xToken,$xTokenSecret,$xAccount)
{ 
    $datatopost = array (
        "token" =>  $xToken,
        "tokenSecret" => $xTokenSecret,
        "account" => $xAccount,
    );

    $ch = curl_init ($xPostURL);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $returnedData = curl_exec ($ch);

    return $returnedData;
}

$firstData = getData("http://www.example.com/foo.php","","","");
$secondData = getData("http://www.example.org/bar.php","","","");
$thirdData = getData("http://www.example.net/helloworld.php","","","");

$merged = array_merge($firstData, $secondData, $thirdData);
```

Now everything is in $merged
(Also did some indenting and changed `echo $returnedData;` to `return $returnedData;` `echo` only displays it, `return` returns it to the variable.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help. How do I need to send the data from the called getData("http://www.example.com/foo.php","","","");? Do I need to use echo, print_r() or return in order to send an array and not a string? My code from the "foo.php" file:  `$resultNames = array();
foreach($arr as $row){ $resultNames[] = $row['name'];
}
print_r($resultNames);
`

Comment: @Tom, it seems, you are making some kind of API, so it better to return xml or json responses from `example.com/*.php` files. You can achieve this by sending, for example, `content-type:application/json` or `content-type:application/xml` headers and then echoing your data in corresponding format.